# Bash flow control issue

Tags: bash, testing, while-loop, break

I have a bash flow control problem which I have resolved with 'while'. Here is a much simplified version:

```
while :; do 
[[ $x = $y ]] || { echo x & y differ; break; }; 
[[ $v -ge $u ]] || { echo v is less than u; break; }; 
echo another test and code; break;
done; 
echo end of tests
```

It consists of a series of unrelated tests followed by some code. The tests have to be done in order until one performs its code. These are the same rules as 'case' but I could not see how to use case for such unrelated tests. Please note that although I have used 'while' there is no loop involved.

Apart from a function what alternative succinct bash structure would others use in this situation?

Comment: `case` isn't applicable here; you aren't just looking at one parameter, and you have non-equality tests. What you have looks fine.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: Removed a link to an answer that has been deleted here.

I once used about the same construction in C (a while loop with a lot of strcmp() commands and a break after finding the right one), but later I realised it was bad (I even made it worse by using a precompiler option defining SWITCH as a while command). Slightly better but still ugly was my second approach, translated in Bash that would be:

```
# Set up testdata
i=1
j=2
k=3
l=4
m=5
n=6
p=1
# Continue testing until test succeeds
okfound=0
test okfound && okfound=$(test $i -eq $j) && echo "i = j"
test okfound && okfound=$(test $i -eq $k) && echo "i = k"
test okfound && okfound=$(test $i -eq $l) && echo "i = l"
test okfound && okfound=$(test $i -eq $m) && echo "i = m"
test okfound && okfound=$(test $i -eq $n) && echo "i = n"
test okfound && okfound=$(test $i -eq $p) && echo "i = p"
test okfound && okfound=$(test $i -eq $j) && echo "i = j"
echo "end of tests"
```

The main reason I looked for a solution like this in C-code, was trying to avoid nested if-then-else indents. In Bash you can use `elif`, I think you should stop trying to find a smart solution, and choose for the simple

```
if   [ $i -eq $j ]; then echo "i = j"
elif [ $i -eq $k ]; then echo "i = k"
elif [ $i -eq $l ]; then echo "i = l"
elif [ $i -eq $m ]; then echo "i = m"
elif [ $i -eq $n ]; then echo "i = n"
elif [ $i -eq $p ]; then echo "i = p"
elif [ $i -eq $j ]; then echo "i = j"
fi
```

Comment: Not so ugly, really.  Certainly no worse than either of the other answers so far.  Easier on the eyes than mine, to be sure, and comparably succinct.

Comment: For this application 'if' could be the most succinct. I will have another look at it.

Comment: I have rarely found 'if' to be succinct  but 'elif' is very useful here and makes it considerably more succinct than anything else I have tried. I think I will use this. Thanks to all for the help.

Comment: Upvote for the second suggestion, which is quite elegant. The first... eek.

Comment: @Walter How? Why have things been removed & why is the public view of this thread not the same as what I see now?

Comment: @John: I have not conducted proper speed tests but it appears that 'if' may be a slightly slower solution than our original ones so perhaps not the best for time critical applications.

Comment: To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `while` loop to establish a scope from which the `break` will exit.  The same control flow could be achieved with nested `if`/`else` statements, but if your real code is indeed much more complicated then that would likely be difficult to follow.

If the `while` loop and the `break`s are distasteful to you, then you could take this approach instead:

```
   { [[ $x != $y ]]  && { echo x '&' y differ; :; }; } \
|| { [[ $v -lt $u ]] && { echo v is less than u; :; }; } \
|| { echo etc. }
```

Note that I have reversed the sense of your conditions, and replaced `break` with `:`.  The latter is unnecessary (`break` could be removed altogether) if you were willing to depend on the preceding command not to fail.

Either way, this is slightly shorter and slightly clearer.  You can't get much more succinct than you already had, though.

Comment: This is interesting. I am not sure what the ':' is doing. I will see if it functions as I want. I should have mentioned that I am trying to use || rather than && where I can as it is going into a launchd which will require & to be encoded as &amp;

Comment: If I understand it correctly the ':' ensures a 'true' exit condition - I will check to see if this is necessary.

Comment: @NevilleHillyer, yes, the `:` does nothing and always succeeds.  Without it, if you execute one of the commands and it fails, then control will pass on to evaluating the next condition.